# Enumeration to integer and vice versa (using combobox itemindex)

Tags: delphi, combobox

Not sure what I am doing wrong here

```
//update controls from main form Tshape
 form2.cbxShape.ItemIndex:= ord(Shape1.Shape);
 form2.cbxColor.Selected:= Shape1.Brush.Color;
 form2.cbxStyle.ItemIndex:= Ord(Shape1.Brush.Style);
 if form2.ShowModal = mrOK then
 begin
  //update main form Tshape from controls
   Shape1.Shape:= TShapeType(form2.cbxShape.ItemIndex);
   Shape1.Brush.Color:= form2.cbxColor.Selected;
   Shape1.Brush.Style:= TBrushStyle(form2.cbxStyle.ItemIndex);
 end;
```

I am not getting the correct shape or brush styles (Color works fine)

Listbox items are as follows:

```
Circle
Ellipse
Rectangle
RoundRect
RoundSquare
Square
```

and

```
BDiagonal
Clear
Cross
DiagCross
FDiagonal
Horizontal
Solid
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the declaration of `TShapeType` and `TBrushStyle`:

> TShapeType = (stRectangle, stSquare, stRoundRect, stRoundSquare,
>   stEllipse, stCircle);
>
> TBrushStyle = (bsSolid, bsClear, bsHorizontal, bsVertical,
>   bsFDiagonal, bsBDiagonal, bsCross, bsDiagCross);

The items in your listboxes must be in the same order, containing the same corresponding enumerations.

Comment: Ahh, i took the values directly from the TShape properties drop down, it seems that they are sorted alphabetically. Thanks for the push in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

The question is already answered by LU RD.
An other method, independed from any sorting, to reach the aim could be

```
implementation
uses TypInfo;
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.ComboBox1CloseUp(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetPropValue(Shape1,'Shape','st' + Combobox1.Text);
  Caption := StringReplace(GetPropValue(Shape1,'Shape',true),'st','',[]);
end;
```